Detailed DC/AC Analysis of Crystal Oscillator Circuit
I'm working on analyzing this crystal oscillator circuit with a temperature control section, and I'm looking for some in-depth help to understand each part of it. Here’s the circuit diagram:

I'm hoping to get guidance on both DC and AC analysis, and I’d like to explore specific cases where certain transistors turn on or off. Here are the main questions I have:

1. DC Analysis

What are the DC operating points (Q-points) for each transistor (Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q4)? I'd like to know the collector, base, and emitter voltages for each one.
How does the regulated vs. unregulated voltage section function? What's the role of the Zener diode (D1) in setting these voltages?
Can someone explain the crystal oven and temperature control section, particularly the role of Q1 and Q2 in maintaining stable conditions for the crystal (Y1)?

2. AC Analysis

How is the oscillation frequency determined, and what role do components like the crystal (Y1), L1, and C3 play in setting or stabilizing it?
How does the AC signal propagate through each transistor stage? What are the factors that contribute to signal amplification across each stage?
Voltage Gain: What formulas should be used to calculate the voltage gain for each transistor stage? If there are multiple formulas, how do I decide which one to use in different parts of the circuit, and how does this impact the overall gain and stability?
What’s the purpose of the buffer amplifier (Q4), and how does it affect the output signal quality and impedance?

3. Case Analysis for Each Transistor

Case 1: When only Q1 is on, what happens in the circuit? Does this initiate any specific process or stabilize part of the circuit?
Case 2: When Q2 turns on (possibly with Q1 active), how does this affect the temperature control loop? How does it interact with the crystal oven?
Case 3: When Q3 activates in the oscillator section, how does it interact with the crystal (Y1), and how does this influence frequency stability?
Case 4: When Q4 (buffer amp) turns on, how does it isolate the output to prevent loading on the oscillator?
Combination Cases: What happens when multiple transistors (e.g., Q2 and Q3, or Q3 and Q4) are active simultaneously? How do these stages affect each other in these situations?

4. Edge Cases and Temperature Effects

Under what conditions (specific voltages, currents, or temperatures) do each of the transistors activate?
How would temperature variations influence the circuit’s behavior, especially in terms of the crystal oven's stability and the oscillation frequency?


Someone here really helped me put together this circuit, but I'm stuck on what to do next and where to place other components. If you have any pointers, that would be great! Here’s a picture of the circuit and a link to the Falstad simulation:
link to simulation


Ethical Programmer - Hi, Where did the schematic come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the answer & add the webpage/PDF/etc. name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the answer & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. (See the [tour] & [help].)

@SamGibson
For an online source:
Shoenbeck, Robert J. Electronics Communication Modulation and Transmission, 2nd ed., Archive.org, https://archive.org/details/electroniccommun00robe, p. 30.
This format includes:

The author's name (Robert J. Shoenbeck).
The title of the book (Electronics Communication Modulation and Transmission).
The edition (2nd ed.).
The source (Archive.org)
The specific page (p. 30).


Ethical Programmer - Thanks, I'll check that shortly. In the meantime, our systems also indicate that at least part of the question is AI-generated. (It also contains mistakes / hallucinations.) What's going on?

@SamGibson Yes, it is AI-generated, but the words are my own. Because English is not my first language, I used GPT for grammar correction. Also, I have removed the least part because it's not necessary. I guess anyone can understand by just looking at the circuit.

Most EEs when wanting figure out things like DC bias points will use a circuit simulator.

You can draw the circuit in a simulator and get most of the answers. Also finding DC bias points is first thing any book tells about transistor amplifier circuits. May I ask what have you tried to solve these questions yourself, as this is not a homework solving service. And most of all, that is two separate unrelated circuits, the heater, and the crystal oscillator. Coupled by temperature only.

@Andyaka
I tried to build and simulate the circuit in Multisim, but I faced some issues and eventually gave up. I then decided to attempt it practically, but things still weren’t making sense to me. A person referred me here, so I asked for help. The first thing I did was try to simulate the circuit, but it’s quite complicated, as it contains four transistors and three sections. It's a large circuit to simulate, and I don't fully understand the oscillator part. So, I reached out for further help here.

@Justme
Nope, why does everyone think that I'm doing homework? It's more about trying to understand circuits in a general way. If I didn't analyze it, how would I know what's actually going on? Why is it a crystal-controlled oscillator? Why does it have three sections, and what is the main role behind each of them?

@EthicalProgrammer You don't get much understanding in a general way, if you start by looking at individual transistors in a circuit, if you are not familiar with (a) what are oscillators in general, (b) what are crystal oscillators, (c) what is an oven controlled oscillator and (d) how does feedback work to keep the temperature stable. I think you should start from a generic electronics book, learn transistor circuits, transistor amplifiers, feedback, and transistor oscillator, and then you would have the tools to answer all your questions. That's a few basic university courses on electronics

This is not a great design to analyze with poor characteristics on the output. several unknowns, and neither a sine wave nor square wave nor low phase noise out.  But you might like my simulation which took 1/2 h to create https://tinyurl.com/295b6o7e Read all the back issues of ED designer circuits submitted like I did before I graduated in 75' to learn circuit analysis faster.

@Justme I know what oscillators, transistors, and all the basic electronics concepts are. I'm actually looking for an in-depth analysis, not a general answer. It seems like you didn’t read the question and just wanted to bag here.

@D.A.S. Thank you so much for the simulation—I really appreciate it! It's a relief to finally have someone who truly wants to help. I’m trying to understand the different operating conditions of each transistor and how to determine their Q points, as I mentioned in my earlier question. Your simulation is a huge help, and I’m working on adapting it to my circuit, but I’m still finding it challenging to get it right. If you have any advice on how to properly set up the Q points or simulate this part, I’d really appreciate it!

First you have to say, what you expect in measurable specs. I have already said this design is not the best.

Use a proper SPICE like MicroCap or LTSpice, or ngspice. Fritzing will not be helpful. You can also use CircuitLab and add a transfer function model of a crystal. It's a slow SPICE, but it should work, but as I said you need to make your own crystal model.

@D.A.S. Okay, after spending hours, I managed to make the circuit look like the one in the diagram posted here. It’s the same, but now the problem is that it’s not running, and I can’t figure out why. Also, how am I supposed to do the DC and AC analysis by the end and study the cases for each transistor? Here’s the modified circuit: https://tinyurl.com/272jlxsv

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I have used CircuitJS for now because it seems easier for me, and I don’t want to make things complicated at this point. If you really want to help, arranging it in LTSpice would be very helpful.

the first one is PNP https://tinyurl.com/28ctqtzz

Where are your test result to analyze expected performance errors?

@D.A.S. One last question!
Thank you so much! I will handle the rest manually. You're a savior! I have one last question: the book provides the values for input impedance, beta, and voltage gain. If you could help me calculate these, that would be great. How do I calculate the voltage gain, beta, and the input impedance? If someone could assist with the calculation, I would really appreciate it! Here's the simulation link Book document link


I'm hoping to get guidance on both DC and AC analysis, and I’d like to explore specific cases where certain transistors turn on or off.


What are the DC operating points (Q-points) for each transistor (Q1, Q2)? I'd like to know the collector, base, and emitter voltages for each one.

Q1 & Q2 are a "thermostat" generator. They are "always" "ON".

Note that vo output is "temperature" ( ~ 80 °C).  Need also R-C load for "thermal" behavior.
Make a DC Analysis for voltages, currents and powers ...
"AC analysis" needed trough "external" temperature variations.
Temperature fixed is around 80 °C.  R3 is a temperature dependent resistor.
Temperature is fixed through the "clip" around R3, Q2 and XTAL.
Made with microcap v12


@D.A.S. Not really. Also this was asked what transistors Q1 and Q2 do.

oops my bad. Nice analysis Antonio. So the +/-4 'C tolerance is based on what? insulation? 1% tolerance stackup? for R3=200 T=80'C. I have done this before with SMD thermistor on 2oz over Kapton around large can and 5mm styrofoam insulating hood with 0.1'C accuracy within 10 seconds switching from 40'C to 70'C to measure fo shift within 0.1 ppm in order to create a general expression for a binned varicap to be programmed in an HC05.

The result was stability = 1ppm from -40 to +70 using a 25 cent +-50 ppm Xtal as VCXO for 928 MHz Tx locked onto to a PLL with 100 ppm autotuning range requirement.  So insulation is an important factor for stability and thermal matching.  Just saying.. a "clip" is OK not always enough.  But the 3rd order expression for all AT cut Xtals was my invention based on all the AT temp curves and this simple 20 second delta T test to measure delta fo from +40 to +70'C . then I could extrapolate to -40'C Cheers Tony.  ( the foamthermal test  was just for the sorting of Xtals circa 30 yrs ago.)

@D.A.S. Yes. Just a clip is not enough. A little well isolated "chamber" would be the best. The specifications needs than some measuring "materials" good enough for evaluating the stability of such a circuit (I don't have these).

5mm styrafoam with stiff 2oz Cu was perfect for a lab test, but $400 SC-cut OCXO's use a bit more of potting in a metal can for 1e-11 stability over mil-temp range, perhaps a double can with 2 zones.

@D.A.S. Your answer is not in line with what I asked. Could you please review the question and answer it accordingly? It would be really helpful not to waste time on the wrong answer. Also, I am looking for the analysis as stated in the question

Dear Ethical; your question is not in line with anyone wanting an analysis / recommendations with no test results. Otherwise you are wasting my pro bono time with 40 yrs of experience and others who suggested a good simulator that works. A good question has clear expectations and specs with results. You have none except a schematic that fails.

You are expecting a lot of answers to many good questions for this antique design, which I would say is far from production ready. Yet I'll share what I know.
WITHOUT values for T, Y1, L1, C1 it is pointless to follow this design or even reverse engineer the AC operating points.
Oven controller uses a 10V Zener reduced by Q1's Vbe of 0.6V to a regulated 9.4V across R1 up and Thermistor T pull down to Q2's Vbe over the thermistor temperature range so that the driver Q2c output to Q2 heats up the insulated oven's temperature of the Xtal, X labels as Y1. When the temperature goes down 1 degree the heat goes up and if 1 degree too high, the heat from Vce x Ic = Pd goes down so it is fairly high gain and extremely sensitive to the values of all resistors and unknown T around Q2. A very sensitive design with resistor tolerance stackup compared to modern bridge versions of thermistor thermometers and precision comparators.
It is possible to spend a lot of time to make it work. Time, which the author did not complete to document here.
Likewise for the Xtal Oscillator.
Italics were my words, the rest is GPT.
Summary of an elementary ovenized sine crystal oscillator intended for AM broadcast.
From your schematic archived link some background is this is an AM band <= 30 ppm crystal oscillator (XO) thus 1 MHz example was given.  I suspect there are regulations for AM broadcasters where one would use a digitally programmable oscillator or OC-VCXO (oven-controlled crystal(X) oscillator with a PLL to derive the precise carrier frequency within 1 ppm or better. But not this design from a 2012 updated reference book on Electronic Communication which has this obsolete design I would recognize from the 60's or 70's.
The DC bias points are basic common emitter rules and even Wiki should define it. Yes, it has it under >>applications. The crystal(Xtal) oscillator or XO is negative feedback type like a Colpitts Osc configuration which originally was based on fixed stable small C-L-C equivalent parts that perform with a Q of 10k stability and up to 100 ppm tuning range and 100 times tighter than a discrete LC oscillator.
However, the design of a clean sine wave oscillator for the carrier of an AM broadcast it is a critical one of tuning all the components around Q3. Missing is the tuning requirement for error frequency which I suspect was beyond the author's scope. The critical values missing include the choke and tuning cap across Q1 C-E.  B
To answer your queries in order;
1. DC Analysis
Q-Points for Transistors
To calculate the DC operating points (collector, base, and emitter voltages) for Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q4:
Q1 (Temperature Control):

The voltage divider formed by R1 and R2 sets the base voltage.
The emitter voltage is roughly Vbase−VBEVbase​−VBE​, assuming VBE≈0.7VVBE​≈0.7V.
The collector voltage depends on the load resistor and current.

Q2 (Temperature Control):

Q2 works in tandem with Q1 to stabilize the crystal oven.
The base voltage of Q2 is influenced by the output of Q1 and its surrounding resistors.

Q3 (Oscillator):

The DC bias is determined by R5, R6, and the connection to the unregulated voltage.
The transistor must be in the active region for oscillation.

Q4 (Buffer Amp):

The voltage divider (R9, R10) sets the base voltage, and the emitter voltage follows.
The collector voltage is determined by R11.

Regulated vs. Unregulated Voltage

The Zener diode (D1) regulates voltage by clamping at a specific value.
It creates a stable reference (regulated +9V) while the unregulated voltage (+13V) serves as the raw input supply.

Crystal Oven and Temperature Control

Q1 and Q2 maintain a stable environment:
Q1 serves as a temperature sensor, adjusting its current based on the temperature.
Q2 acts as a driver, adjusting power to the oven to stabilize the crystal's temperature.

2. AC Analysis
Oscillation Frequency

The frequency is primarily determined by the crystal (Y1) in conjunction with surrounding components (e.g.,C1, L1, C3).
Y1 sets a very stable frequency due to its physical properties.
- C3 fine-tunes the frequency by forming a resonant load capacitance value but using the current multiplication of hFE to increase the tuning cap value and current. The negative DC feedback with positive AC feedback that builds up the voltage to a stable AC level.

Signal Propagation

The signal starts in the oscillator section (Q3) and propagates through Q4 to the output.
Amplification depends on the transistor's configuration (e.g., common emitter provides high gain).

Voltage Gain

Gain Calculation:
For common-emitter stages (e.g., Q3 and Q4), use Av=−Rc/Re. (collector resistance divided by emitter resistance).
For stages with bypass capacitors, Re​ is bypassed, increasing gain with Ac impedance near 0 at f.

Choosing the Formula:

Use small-signal analysis, considering the configuration of each stage (e.g., feedback, bypass capacitors).

Buffer Amplifier (Q4)

Q4 isolates the oscillator from the load, preventing impedance changes that could destabilize the oscillation frequency.

3. Case Analysis for Each Transistor
Case 1: Q1 On

Q1 adjusts the current to stabilize the oven's temperature.
If Q1 alone is on, it initiates feedback for thermal stability.

Case 2: Q2 On

When Q2 turns on, it drives current into the oven to maintain the crystal's optimal temperature.

Case 3: Q3 On

Q3 amplifies the oscillation signal. Its interaction with Y1 ensures frequency stability. (using positive AC feedback)

Case 4: Q4 On

Q4 buffers the output signal, ensuring a clean and stable output without affecting the oscillator.

Combination Cases

Q2 and Q3: Temperature stabilization and oscillation occur simultaneously.
Q3 and Q4: Oscillation and buffering ensure signal integrity and proper output.

4. Edge Cases and Temperature Effects
Conditions for Activation

Transistors activate when their base-emitter voltage exceeds 0.7V.

Specific voltages and currents depend on the circuit bias and 'components excess saturation of transistor as shorting switch and thus Re=0 and Av is maximum that internal Rbe will permit and cause fast rising pulse from the midpoint of the sine causing extreme distortion. The proper way to run a sine oscillator is to regulate a sine current. But this is complex in this simple design so the Colpitts uses a pulse of current and expects the the Q small BW to ring into a sine wave with a linear gain.  The initial test for this design is a hugely distorted sine wave until critical biasing for current gain can minimize the excess gain. Below this state of loss and gain balance of unity gain is called the "Barkhausen Criteria" for stable non-oscillating amplifiers. The lower the positive feedback < 1 the better, is called "gain margin. But in this case, we want oscillation so a sinewave has a AC gain of +1.00 and a pulse is anything much higher to speed up the slope. It is harder to regulate and requires tuning here with this unfortunate design.'



Temperature Variations

Temperature changes affect the crystal oven. If the oven's temperature isn't controlled:
- The crystal frequency will drift over a wide temperature range determined by the minute of the degree of the angle of the Xtal "AT-cut" and rated something like 25, or 50 to 100 ppm over xx degrees C  due to thermal expansion or contraction of the atomic lattice of synthetic quartz. (If you search for AT temp curves you can find it. But this isn't how you order them. It's just a way of understanding thermal drift is a third-order effect which has tradeoffs for temp range and error.*
Q1 and Q2 mitigate these effects by adjusting oven power dynamically.
'- yet are sensitive to thermal differences by ambient conditions so the oven needs adequate TBD insulation.'

I approve this message produced by GPT4 with edits and corrections from myself in italics. I copied the schematic and question entirely into GPT4 and took the first answer. Normally, I would say, "Are you sure?" But I still had to edit the bold and bullets while watching a movie. So it wasn't a complete time-waster to prepare this historical design that never made it to production. (tell-tale signs)

Impedance added:
The Buffer Q4, is a current gain amplifier with gain ratios of Rc/Re = Av for AC signals.  Since the DC bias is fixed, Beta affects impedance in both directions (B to E) as a multiplier to Re to the input Rin=Zin and a divider seen by emitter as base resistance divided by Beta or \$\beta ~(aka h_{FE})\$

One last question!
Thank you so much! I will handle the rest manually. You're a savior! I have one last question: the book provides the values for input impedance, beta, and voltage gain. If you could help me calculate these, that would be great. How do I calculate the voltage gain, beta, and the input impedance? If someone could assist with the calculation, I would really appreciate it! Here's the simulation link Book document link

did u just deleted smth?

Wiki was not so great on that description and better ones by @jonk were written on this site (i.e. search for jonk) for common emitter or CE configuration and all transistors models. So I appended my GPT answer.  Read all of Jonk's answers for a bonus experience.  Invoice is in the mail ;)

If this is for your credit, cite references.

?...................?

I am still not getting the required answer as stated in the book. The book says the input impedance is 7.2 kΩ, beta is 150, and the voltage gain is 2.70.
I calculated only beta using simulation, and it came out to be 100, which doesn't match the book. I also tried calculating it practically, but the answers were totally different. Additionally, I checked the voltage gain formula from your wiki, and it came out to be 2.75, which is a 0.5 difference. For the input impedance, I calculated it like this: R9 * R10 / (R9 + R10), but the result was something else.

The sim. used Beta = 100, you can change that part to 150

Alright, how to change it AND what about the rest of the calculation ? input impedance and voltage gain can u do it?

My time is up.  https://tinyurl.com/2xnujaj7   use your mouse and learn the theory

Amen !!!!!!!!!!
